# Remove unused JavaScript for Google Recaptcha don´t work for me

Tags: wordpress, performance-testing, recaptcha

in this site:
https://kunstkeramikk.no/

Page Speed Insights says:
Remove unused JavaScript for Google Recaptcha

have tried to use the solution proposed in this post but it does not work for me

[Page Speed Insights Remove unused JavaScript for Google Recaptcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62334094/page-speed-insights-remove-unused-javascript-for-google-recaptcha)

```
 `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_deregister_scripts' );
function mytheme_deregister_scripts() {
  if( is_home() || is_front_page() ) :
    wp_deregister_script('google-invisible-recaptcha');
  endif;
}`   
    
    
How can I solved this?
thank you
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the id of the script you want to de-register. I don't see an script tag with the id="google-invisible-recaptcha" in your source code. I see an id of 'et-recaptcha-v3-js'.

So change `wp_deregister_script('google-invisible-recaptcha');` to `wp_deregister_script('et-recaptcha-v3');`

```
// Updated code

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_deregister_scripts', 999 );
function mytheme_deregister_scripts() {
  if( is_home() || is_front_page() ) :
    wp_deregister_script('et-recaptcha-v3');
  endif;
}
```

I also added a high priority of 999.